# TextInput in ViewPager unfocusssing due to KeyboardAvoidingView?

Tags: react-native, keyboard, expo, react-native-textinput, react-native-pager-view

I've read multiple questions regarding an existing issue with the PagerView library being combined with the KeyboardAvoidingView. All of the asked questions didn't lead me to a full solution. Multiple stated that the behavior of the KeyboardAvoidingView needed to be changed to only padding, which caused my view to not work at all. Is there another workaround or full solution to this problem?

**Behaviour**

Pressing on the input field makes the keyboard appears and disappears immediately. (it's not willing to focus).

I've posted a [screenrecording](https://youtu.be/-TBui_D0TxQ) on YouTube.

**Expected behavior**

The keyboard should just stay in focus whenever the input field is pressed.

Comment: Could you please describe your expected behavior and actual behavior a bit more? It would help the people who want to help you a lot :)

Comment: When focussing on my input field in my pagerview (trying to fill in something) my keyboard appears and disappears immediately (it's not willing to focus).

Comment: Does this happen both on Android and iOS?

Comment: It does, problem still hasn't been solved.

Comment: Its more a workaround then a fix but you could try this; https://github.com/callstack/react-native-pager-view/issues/155#issuecomment-607457924

Comment: And maybe it's worth reading through this article https://medium.com/@nickyang0501/keyboardavoidingview-not-working-properly-c413c0a200d4 

I would like to help you but I need an example project on Github or something. The video unfortunately isn't enough information